# Why does an external user has denied access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I need to grant an external user access to a specific folder in a document library. I have given the user Contribute and Read directly. But the user still doesn't have access. When I check the permissions for the user I can see a whole bunch of deny access.

[image: User has a lot of deny permissions]

How can I remove the deny access for a specific external user so they can access the folder?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could stop inheriting permission in this library first, then reset these user access to this library.

Comment: The folder already wasn't inheriting permissions. I tried to delete unique permissions and then stop inheriting permissions, but the user still have all those Deny permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try delete unique permission and then restore inheritance by PowerShell. The  article for you to have a reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/sharepoint-online-delete-unique-permissions-using-powershell.html